# Do I have to run make/make install to test each change to a Perl distribution file?

Tags: perl, testing

Do I have to run `make` and `make install` each time I change a `.pm` file for Perl? I'm doing a ton of testing and this is becoming cumbersome.

Comment: You probably shouldn't 'make install' at all until you're done testing.  Use 'make test'.

Comment: I downvoted because I'm befuddled at the accepted answer, and don't believe the question clearly communicates the problem.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear and the accepted answer is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on module setup, but under the standard MakeMaker I use, "make test" runs a "make" if any files have been modified, so when doing intra-module development "make test" is the only command you need until you've finished.

Comment: I don't even see how this is close to a 'good' answer, all he is claiming is that his make-system has logic to only rebuild if needed -- like every make system, and that it is run under `test` too. You still have to run `make test` and it still has to run `make`, furthermore you never said anything about testing anywhere in the question, nor did you mention using XS or anything that would require compilation.

Comment: @Evan, you may not see how this is a good answer, but it is the right answer. It works reliably in all situations, whereas yours does not.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question: the question doesn't mention testing. The question mentions installing. The answer mentions testing and not installing. The answer also mentions MakeMaker which is not present in the question.

Comment: I think you missed the word "test" in the question. Read it again. It'a always been there, as has "make".

Comment: No, I think you added the word "test", per the history of the question.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to install the module to test it.

If I'm testing inside my distribution directory, I just use the `test` target:

```
 % make test
```

Or, if I'm using Module::Build:

```
 % ./Build test
```

Since `make` is a dependency management tool, it also takes care of any other steps it needs to perform so it can run the `test` target. You don't need to run each target separately. Module::Build does the same thing.

If I want to test a single file, I combine the `make` command with a call to `perl` that also uses the `blib` module to set the right `@INC`:

```
 % make; perl -Mblib t/single_test.t
```

Some people like using `prove` for the same thing. No matter which method I use, I'm probably using the arrow keys to move back to a previous command line to re-run it. I do very little typing in any of this.

Answer (score 1):

Evan Carroll got it basically right. To expand on his answer: use the testing tools that come with Perl to tighten the workflow.

Let's say you are in your project directory and you hack on the files in its `lib/` subdirectory. Execute [`prove -l`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?prove) to run all tests. That's easier than messing with absolute paths in the `PERL5LIB` environment variable.

Comment: I assumed the purpose of `make install` was to run applications -- though I can now see it being used to run tests. I use `prove` all day long, sometimes I take for granted other people don't know about it.

Answer (score -2):

Presumably you're editing a lib module in a non-lib location, rather than clobbering a global library for each modification - do the sensible thing and change the library path perl uses with `PERL5LIB`, which will append internally to `@INC` (the `use` search path):

```
PERL5LIB=/home/user/code/perl/project/lib perl myapp.pl
```

If your program isn't pure-perl and requires a make system, there is no way to do this short of rebuilding, but pure-perl (PP) doesn't really require `make` under normal circumstances. If you do it this way, running perl under a normal environment will yield the predictable and tested results, running it with your `PERL5LIB` will allow *you* to test the program.

Comment: Don't do it this way. Don't get into the habit of testing what is in lib. Use the build system to put things into blib and test from there so you don't get into this bad habit and wonder why it doesn't work in some cases. It's so much easier to do it the right way that works in every case.

Comment: Is it the right way because it is your way, or is the right way for some substantial other reason? I don't think you read my posts, I think you stalk me and drop in with silly reasons to downvote. My context of test, was a real world application not a unit test, as unit tests aren't mentioned in the question. But, I would agree, if it was a unit test, you're better off not messing with PERL5LIB, and using prove. (which I had said above when it was assumed the question pertained to a unit test).

Comment: It's not my way. I didn't make it up. It is better on its merits, though. Don't flatter yourself about stalking and victim fantasies.

Comment: Geez Evan, lay off the guy.  I've been watching you defensively comment-snipe brian all over ST.